# Error query chaincode: MSP DEFAULT is unknown

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have deployed the example ["first network"](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) from the Hyperledger Fabric demo. When I run this:

```
./byfn.sh -m up
```

it performs without errors. While the docker is still up and running, I try to run

```
peer query -C mychannel -n mycc -c {"Args":["query","a"]}
```

and I receive an error:

> "failed to deserialize identity, err MSP DEFAULT is unknown".

I made some research but found no help. Anyone has an idea?
Sorry, I hope I am right here in this channel. Thanks a lot in advance!
The query is copied from script.sh, which is called by

```
./byfn.sh -m up
```

Somehow it does not work if I run it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What missing in your question is where exactly are you running the:

```
peer query -C mychannel -n mycc -c {"Args":["query","a"]}
```

For `peer cli` to be able run correctly there is a set of environmental variable you have to provide. Basically you need to point to the endorsing peer and to the MSP configuration, setting the MSP ID as well. So my educative guess would be, that you haven't configured those values, hence there error.

In order to solve you problem you can:

1. Connect to the `cli` docker image initialized and running after you did

`$ ./byfn -m up`

by invoking `$ docker exec -it cli /bin/bash`

which will prompt you to already configured container with parameters I've explained above.

2. An alternative would be to setup those parameters on your own, for instance:

```
$ export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=endorsing_peer_IP:7051
$ export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
$ export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/tmp/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp
```

where `endorsing_peer_IP` is the IP of the endorsing peer, and `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` points to the MSP dir.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right. Well done! Option 1 works for me. Option I have not tried.